# Java JasperReports Barcode print

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to print Bar code labels using `JasperReports` reporting. I have properly design the Jasper report and I can preview it using `iReport`. But when I pass parameter to jasper report via Java application bar code report never generated.

following code are used

```
//Print barcode
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection conn = (Connection) 
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///miracleposdb", "root", "mysql");


    String reportSource = "../src/reports/barcode.jrxml"; /* Report Path*/
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("printid", lblbarcodeID.getText());

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource); /*Compiling  */

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            params, DB.MiraclePOS.connect());  /*Filling report*/
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);   /*For Print*/

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Did you check the `printid` parameter in resulting report (you can add the `textField` with `$P{printid}` expression to  the `Title` band, for example)?

Comment: yes It works, Only report not generate when add bar-code to the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `jrxml` file, the barcode section should be something like below:

In my case I used **barcode4j**

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="353" y="42" width="200" height="50"/>
        <jr:Code39 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" textPosition="bottom">

            <jr:codeExpression>                 
                <![CDATA[$P{printid}]]>                     
            </jr:codeExpression>                
       </jr:Code39>
</componentElement>
```

I use netbean report viewer to generate the PDF view and it works for me.

**NOTE:**

When you drag&drop barcode using iReport the barcord section of jrxml should have empty CDATA:

```
<![CDATA[]]>
```

If you generate PDF in this condition then the barcord won't show up since there is no value.

Also make sure to set parameter using iReport.

Hope this helps.